# account association for 100 StackOverflow rep

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I have just created a new account on networkengineering.stackexchange.com. How can I earn 100 rep on my StackOverflow account? I've read a number of posts on stackexchange regarding account associations, but I still don't quite understand how to gain this 100 rep.

Thanks!

Comment: "you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)"

Comment: So you only get +100 rep when you have 200 or more rep in your account?

Comment: Yes. You need to have 200 or more rep (on any site), in order to get the +100 rep association bonus.